# code not working in Jelly Beans

Tags: android, json

I have this code which returns `Json` object from url.
It works fine in `froyo` but the same code is not working in `Jelly Beans`.

Is something wrong with my code ?

Please help me, here is my code

```
    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {

    // initialize
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

Here is my log error

`11-01 11:01:48.437: E/log_tag(1044): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-01 11:01:48.437: E/log_tag(1044): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 11:01:48.437: E/log_tag(1044): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`

Comment: is there any error? if yes then please post it. And yes you are doing network related task so make sure you are not doing this in main thread see [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: what is the problem exactly just see logcat whether any error is there or not??

Comment: it shows me this error first `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` but i have checked the internet connection in emulator as well as in manifest. The code is working fine in `froyo` but the same code is not working in `Jelly Beans` . I am trying to read `Json` from `Json object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android API v15, it requires no heavy process working on main thread. So you should move your logic to another thread like bellow source code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
        // your logic
   }                        
}).start();
```

More information please refer
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html

Comment: you are right Chirag Patel, need to divide task in separate thread

Comment: yes it solved my problem :) can you tell me how can i update UI ? I am getting value in log .

Comment: i am getting my value from `json.getString('fname')` i want this value on my `TextView` any idea ?

Comment: just store String test=json.getString('fname'); and Textview.settext(test);

Comment: but it gives error because we are doing this in a seprate thread

Comment: ok.so variable declare globle and use it out of thread.getting ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to establish network connection on the main thread. Instead use `AsyncTask`.
Because network tasks are long tasks .  In froyo you can establish network on main thread but in Later versions of android you will have to use `Async Task`.

Answer (score 1):

Make Server call in background thread.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONObject jObject = getJSONfromURL("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2248907%22&format=json");
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
public JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {

    // initialize
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its error about `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`
Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do network related task.

In another way you can disable this by using this code on your `onCreate()`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

But see disabling `StrictMode` policy is not a good idea, so you better to go with `AsyncTask`